# Calculate MKCoordinateRegion with a fixed diagonal distance

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I want to calculate a MKCoordinateRegion with a diagonal distance of 30km and the proportions of the region should be the same as the maps frame. 
My approach looks like this:

```
    let alpha = atan(mapView.frame.width / mapView.frame.height).radiansToDegrees
    let beta = 90 - alpha

    let spanDiagonal = 30_000.0
    let spanWidth = spanDiagonal * Double(cos(beta.degreesToRadians))
    let spanHeight = sqrt(spanDiagonal * spanDiagonal + spanWidth * spanWidth)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.centerCoordinate, spanWidth, spanHeight)
    let tlLat = region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0)
    let tlLong = region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0)
    let brLat = region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0)
    let brLong = region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0)

    let tl = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tlLat, longitude: tlLong)
    let br = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: brLat, longitude: brLong)
    print(MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPointForCoordinate(tl), MKMapPointForCoordinate(br)))
```

I calculated the angle of the frame and then a triangle with this angle and a base of 30000. This resulted in what I thought the right span height and width.

The problem that I have is that the diagonal of the region is about 10km larger. I think the cause for this is the conversion of meters to degrees that is somehow wrong.

Do you see a problem with my approach or do you know any better way to calculate a region with the same proportions of the frame, a diagonal of 30km and the same center as the map?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this](https://github.com/timsearle/Euclid) awesome library which implements the Euclid algorithm and allows you to expand a bounding box around a coordinate. Exactly what I was looking for!